# Local storage - save DOM changes done with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, local-storage

I am trying to figure out how to store DOM changes done with vanilla JavaScript in local storage but so far unable to figure it out.

This is a short cut out from the JavaScript code that do several more changes to the DOM.

The function is called by a button on the webpage.

```
function myFunction() 
{
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";

    var element = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); 
    for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
    element[i].style.color = "black";
    element[i].style.backgroundColor = "#565969";
    element[i].style.borderColor = "black";
    element[i].style.boxShadow = "inset 0 0 5px black";}
}
```

Have seen it is easier with two CSS to shift between, but would like to know how to solve the problem above.

Comment: Just store the styles in a JSON. You could even set the styles of the element, then stringify it's `style` parameter and save that.

Comment: Why can't you use a class and stylesheet rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check localstorage for the DOM values first, if its there you make use of it otherwise you apply new DOM values.

```
function myFunction() {
    var DOMValues = {};
    var storageContent = localStorage.getItem('cssProps');

    if (storageContent) {
      DOMValues = JSON.parse(storageContent);
      manipulateDOM(DOMValues);
    } else {
      DOMValues = {
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
        color: 'black'
      };

      localStorage.setItem('cssProps', JSON.stringify(DOMValues));
      manipulateDOM(DOMValues);
    }
}


function manipulateDOM (props) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = props.backgroundColor;

    var element = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
      element[i].style.color = props.color;
      element[i].style.backgroundColor = props.backgroundColor;
    }
}
```

Comment: That works, but there was another question that I forgot to add to my first post. That is how does one load the save local storage if entering a new page on the same webpage? Also how to remove the changes made to local storage, in other words use the regular CSS on the webpage.

Comment: `localStorage.removeItem('cssProps')` will remove the item

Comment: If page 1 and page 2 uses the same JS script, you just have a function that checks for localStorage content, then call that function anywhere from page 1 or page 2